# when exactly does the wcf autocomplete execute?

Tags: wcf, autocomplete, msdtc, distributed-transactions

I would like to know if I have a WCF service that has a TransactionScopeRequired but I don't use a transactional binding...

Is possible to return a message first and later the transaction could make a rollback?

In other workds... which executes first? the returning of the message or the commit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the transaction is committed when the service operation finishes executing, and before the response is returned.